# How to add new Split (row) to a MultiSplitPane in Java?

Tags: java, jxmultisplitpane, multisplitpane

I have a simple MultiSplitPane in java. It has 1 Row (split) and 2 nodes (Leaves) in it. How can I add another row under the existing one.

Here's the code that creates the MultiSplitPane and the 2 Leaves:

```
List children = 
Arrays.asList(new Leaf("left"),
new Divider(), 
new Leaf("right"));
Split modelRoot = new Split();
modelRoot.setChildren(children);

MultiSplitPane multiSplitPane = new MultiSplitPane();
multiSplitPane.getMultiSplitLayout().setModel(modelRoot);
multiSplitPane.add(new JButton("Left Component"), "left");
multiSplitPane.add(new JButton("Right Component"), "right");
```

This is how I can add another Leaf, but I need to add new Split (row):

```
Leaf newLeaf = new Leaf("newLeaf");
    Split newSplit = (Split) multiSplitPane.getMultiSplitLayout().getModel();
    java.util.List newList = new ArrayList();

    newList.add(newLeaf);
    newList.add(new Divider());
    newList.addAll(newSplit.getChildren());

    newSplit.setChildren(newList);

    multiSplitPane.setModel(newSplit);
    multiSplitPane.add(new JButton("new"), "newLeaf");
    revalidate();
```

Comment: In most UI API's, you do this by placing the existing divider and leafs (?) in a composite widget and then placing a divider under that composite and above another leaf.  Not exactly sure about this specific API set, but the concept should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with a second Split, you can do the following:

- Create a couple components to put inside the second Split.
- Make Leafs to which you will link the above components.
- Make a new children list representing the Split's structure.
- Create the Split and set its children to the above list.

That's the easy part. Now, here is the key:

- Add your second Split to the **first Split's** children list. Note that you may have to add a divider to the first Split's children list before the second split!
- Call "setChildren" for your first Split. From what I can tell, you must do this after having revised the Split's children list.
- Don't forget to actually add your components to the MultiSplitPane and call "revalidate" for the MultiSplitPane.

Take a look at [this sample code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848566/swing-layout-manager-solution-to-replace-dynamically-created-and-nested-split-pa/12879025#12879025)